# Selenium on Linux: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver_linux64' executable may have wrong permissions

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape a particular page for my project using beautiful soup and pandas library. But, while executing the code and even though providing the chrome browser path, I am getting this error. What shall I do in order to make my code run?

I am doing this code on Linux and I tried doing this:

```
chromedriver = "/home/sharvari/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64"
 os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver '''
 driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
```

instead of my original code:

```
import os
from Django.utils import timezone
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def fetch():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/sharvari/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64')
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=iphone&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as=off")
    content = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
```

I expected it to open my Chrome browser and fetch data from the URL provided. But instead, I am redirected to Chrome and then this error message is displayed:

```
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sharvari/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/home/sharvari/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 769, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/home/sharvari/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1516, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/sharvari/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sharvari/Documents/Internship/Codes/webscrape.py", line 31, in <module>
    fetch()
  File "/home/sharvari/Documents/Internship/Codes/webscrape.py", line 15, in fetch
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/sharvari/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64')
  File "/home/sharvari/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/sharvari/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 88, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver_linux64' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```